# Vaadin scrolls window top on every field change

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

We've been migrating Vaadin application from Vaadin 6 to Vaadin 7. Everything looks fine except of one thing: every time I change any input value and lose focus, my window scrolls to top. In my debug tool window in Chrome I see vaadin sends response with string like `"31":{"scrollTop":300}}` included. I don't see any code that explicitly calls scrollTop() or any such thing. In which direction should I dig to solve this problem?

**Update:**

I've attached a screenshot of layout debug info: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1405291/stackoverflow/19481515-screenshot.png

**Update:**

It seems like ajax request being sent to server itself includes "scrollTop" variable change, and Vaadin just processes this request. Still I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: I think this has something to do with your specific layout. Any chance you might post a screenshot of the screen and which layoutcontainers are used?

Comment: Here is the screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1405291/stackoverflow/19481515-screenshot.png

Any change in these multiple fields, and form scrolls to the top.

Comment: "Any change in these multiple fields" = Any change in any fields

Comment: I ran into the similar issue, added a bug report on dev.vaadin.com: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12972

Comment: The description of the issue looks very much like the one described in another discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979365/table-scroll-bar-jumps-up-when-table-receives-focus-in-ie

Answer (score -1):

```
UI.getCurrent().setScrollTop(0);
```

Comment: What this answer is expected to solve? This is what I wanted to avoid